# Question about the strong law of large numbers (to build understanding)

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

I'm learning about the LLN and CLT for the first time and I'm having some trouble. I've read through other posts but I have a quirky (likely dumb) question about denominators...

> The Strong LLN says for $X_1,...,X_n$ iid with common mean $\mu$,
>
> $$P \left( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{X_1 + ... + X_n }{n} = \mu \right) = 1$$

**My question 1:** Instead of dividing by $n$, is it true that if I divide by a function of $n$, say $f(n) = Cn^k$ where $k \ge 1$ then the limit will converge to some constant always? (not necessarily $\mu$)

$$P \left( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{X_1 + ... + X_n }{f(n)} = \text{some constant} \right) = 1$$

I believe this is true because $Var\left(\frac{S_n}{f(n)}\right) = \frac{n \sigma^2}{(f(n))^2}$ and as long as $f(n)$ grows as fast as $n$ then the variance will go to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

**My question 2:** If instead of dividing by $n$ in the Strong LLN, if I divide by $ \sigma\sqrt{n}$ then is it true that

$$P \left( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{X_1 + ... + X_n }{\sigma \sqrt{n}} = \text{some constant} \right) \neq 1$$

and it won't "converge" to a constant because the RV $\frac{S_n}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$ is a Normal RV with variance $1$.

**My question 3:** It seems to me what you divide $S_n$ by is very important and can lead to very different results like the LLN or CLT... is that a somewhat correct way of thinking?

Thank you!!

Comment: Please also quote the conditions on the random variables.

Comment: Ah yes the $X_i$'s are all iid. I will edit it.

Comment: That's still incomplete.  Take $\Omega = \Bbb{N}$ and $X_i = id_{\Bbb N}$ to see this.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 hmmm... well I mean whatever conditions that they introduce for beginners when learning the LLNs... sorry, unfortuantely I don't know the notation in what you wrote, $X_i = id_{\Bbb N}$ - it seems $X_2  = 2d_{\Bbb N} \neq 3d_{\Bbb N} = X_3$ and so they are not iid but I think I just don't understand the notation

Comment: I mean the identity function on N.  $X_i(w) = w$ for all w,i in N.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 ahhh I see thanks... what should I add to the conditions to make it work? Specify that the $X_i$'s are RVs but not constant RV's?

Comment: I encourage you to wiki it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding 1 and 2: If you divide by $Cn^k$ then the limit will be $\mu/C$ (if $k=1$) or $0$ (if $k>1$). When $k<1$ the result will be $\infty$ with the same sign as $\mu$ unless $\mu=0$, in which case the situation is more complicated.

Regarding 3, yes: essentially you have different results when you measure deviation of the sample mean from the population mean in different scales relative to $n$. Under "typical" circumstances (when $X_i$ has a MGF existing in a neighborhood of $0$):

- $O(1)$ scale fluctuations asymptotically vanish (this is LLN)
- $O(n^{-1/2})$ scale fluctuations persist with probability strictly between $0$ and $1$ (this is CLT)
- $O(1)$ scale fluctuations decay exponentially fast in probability (this is Cramer's theorem, a type of large deviation principle).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Before I learned about the LLN/CLT, I divided RVs like $S_n$ by constants all the time and it wasn't a big deal. The result would still be a RV and what the constant actually was would not dramatically change the outcome. But for LLN/CLT it seems what you divide $S_n$ by as $n$ goes to infinity has really big impact...

Comment: by the way should the third bullet point maybe be $O(n^k)$ for $k>1$? Again thanks for your help.

Comment: @HJ_beginner These are fluctuations of the sample mean around the population mean. The third bullet point is just a more precise version of the first one (but with stronger hypotheses being required): it gives a quantitative estimate of the convergence rate of $P(|\overline{X}-\mu|>\epsilon)$.

Comment: ahh thanks for the clarification!!